# Is it possible to run a Qt 5.10 programm on XP?

Tags: qt, qt5, windows-xp

I have deployed a 5.10 32bit msvc `programm.exe` and it works ok on windows 8.1. But I have to run it on XP and I can not do it. It says "`progamm.exe is not a valid Win32 app`". Am I doomed? Do I have to use the last version of Qt that supports XP, like Qt5.6?
Thank you!

Comment: Yes, you should use an older version of Qt:  https://wiki.qt.io/PlatformSupport. XP is not supported after the 5.6.

Comment: @IAmInPLS so no for 5.10 on XP?

Comment: Exactly, it's not possible to run a Qt5.10 program on XP.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The latest version that supports XP is Qt 5.6.3. The Windows XP support is not enabled by default. You have to download the Qt [source-code](https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/5.6/5.6.3/) and compile it with `./configure -target xp`. This means, if you install Qt 5.6.3 (pre-built) package the Windows XP support is not enabled! You must compile the source-code.
Qt 5.6.3 is in strict phase and reliable if you want to support Windows XP, which is still installed on many computers in China, India, etc.

Qt 5.6.3 is upwards compatible and supports additional to Windows XP, Windows Vista, Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows 10.

Qt 5.7 and upwards **do not** support Windows XP. If you modify the PE-Header to make it run, it's likely that the application will crash from time to time as Windows APIs are required that are not available on Windows XP.

Comment: Thank you! But the question is not actual any more. The Head told me to use the latest version of qt. They will upgrade to win10 IoT.

Comment: 5.7 should [still work](https://forum.qt.io/topic/101054/mingw-on-xp), at least if you don't require anything from networking. Of course then, the newer the versions the more likely you are to hit some unavailable function.

Comment: `The latest version that supports XP is Qt 5.6.3` it is wrong. 5.7 also works. Sometimes just need to a add `.dll` files manualy.