# How do I implement a "thread safe asynchronous library loading" mechanism in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, shared-libraries

My program needs to access loads of shared libraries to extract factory information from them. Now all libs are not good behaving and some may crash. So obviously this "scanning" operation cannot continue on the main thread. I need a way to gracefully terminate and report an exception when a thread crashes scanning a particular library and restart that thread. I will be using Qt with C++.
Now these libraries are at various locations in the system and for speeding up this scanning task, I spawn multiple threads for that purpose. Now I want to make it like all the "scanner" threads report to a common thread/process about the files they will be scanning and each thread will be aware what the other is scanning so double checking will not occur. I will also need to unload the libraries which are finished with to save RAM as these libraries can often be in 100s of MB. I also do not want to use file-locking for that purpose as other software could be accessing that library.
Remember I want to keep this cross platform. I read in Boost's DLL library docs that on MacOS, from a single process multiple threads cannot be accessing dlopen_/dlclose_. Although Windows and Linux suppport it.
If you understood what I want to make and have a better idea for this "thread safe asynchronous library loading" mechanism, please answer. Also if this idea is good please explain with a little code to help me understand that.
Sorry for no formatting. I typed this on mobile.

Comment: This question is probably too broad for SO. If a dll is unstable you need to load it on a different process. You might use something like gRPC to communicate.

Comment: @doron : I like these types of questions, requesting something more than fast-food recipes and code ready for lazy copy/paste. I like your comment as well, and I would transform it into a slightly longer answer.

Answer (score 0):

Digging a bit deeper into @doron's proposal, and trying to fulfill your Qt-related requirement I would also propose that the extractor task be executed by a subprocess. A command line program taking as parameter the library path and name, and writing to the standard output returning his factory information probably would suffice. This would be orchestrated from the main process with [QProcess](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html) reading from standard output on success or receiving an error signal when not. If the returned information needs to be very complex or large, I would think on [QSharedMemory or other IPC method offered by Qt](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/ipc.html).

Comment: Thanks for your help, but unfortunately I want to make a program which is compatible with even Windows XP. Now Qt 4.8 is the latest version which supports XP. It will be unnecessarily heavy. Hence I plan on using Sciter for UI and whatever Boost/C++11 offers for the backend. Sciter is much much better than Qt Quick or Widgets in Qt 4.8

Comment: [Qt 5.6](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.6/supported-platforms.html) supports XP if you compile it yourself, according to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50255414/is-it-possible-to-run-a-qt-5-10-programm-on-xp)

Comment: that is too long and tedious for the purpose of my application. also probably it supports only sp3